# Making a DIV clickable for touchscreens

Tags: jquery, click, touchscreen

I've made a website with a clickable DIV:

```
jQuery("#add").on('click', function(e){
addlist();
});
```

It works on desktops, but not on touchscreens. I hope there is someone who could tell me how to make it clickable on touchscreens too.

Comment: have you tried with 'hover' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tap` event [provided](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) by jquery mobile.

> The jQuery Mobile tap event triggers after a quick, complete touch event that occurs on a single target object. It is the gesture equivalent of a standard click event that is triggered on the release state of the touch gesture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to use this event